# Passing structure from VC++ to C#

Tags: c#, dll, visual-c++, structure

I'm using C# DLL in a VC++ application. I have some details in VC++ like

```
PageNumer
pageTitle
PageDesc
BoxDetail
```

I have to pass these to C# DLL. So I made one structure in VC++, then I pass that to C#. But I couldn't do that. Please help me.

VC++ Function:

```
struct SCS3OverVwPg
{
 __int32 iOvrPgNo;      
 char sOvrPgTitle[30]; //OverView Page Title
};


void CToolTab::SendOverview()
{ 
    SCS3OverVwPg *pOverVw = 0;
    pOverVw = new SCS3OverVwPg;    
    Globals1::gwtoolbar->SetTree(pOverVw);
}
```

C# function:

```
public struct SCS3Over
{
    Int32 iOvrPgNo;
    char[] sOvrPgTitle;
}

public void SetTree(SCS3Over x)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Data received");          

}
```

If I do like this, it shows the error

> error C2664: 'Tabcontrol::ToolBar::SetTree' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'SCS3OverVwPg *' to 'SCS3Over'

If I change name in C# DLL to `SCS3OverwPg`, it shows `error of structure redifinition`. Please help me.

Comment: Is your C++ code written in C++/CLI or plain C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will have to assume you are using managed C++...

Instead of redeclaring the struct in managed C++, just reference the struct type from the C# assembly, and use that when calling the function.